# nginx + php-fpm configuration. Server stalls

Tags: configuration, nginx, php

Running a server with 140 000 page views a day (analytics). 
php-fpm processes go for about 10-12M each.
Servers got 10G ram, mysql goes for 1.2G-1.6G

Configuration looks like this:

```
nginx

user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
     access_log off;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  10;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

        server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

php-fpm like this:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = webadmin
group = webadmin
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 900
pm.start_servers = 900
pm.min_spare_servers = 200
pm.max_spare_servers = 900
pm.max_requests = 500
chdir = /
```

Typically the server can run just fine with 500 simultaneous users (again, real time google analytics used to get this estimate) but stall at times where users are not that many (75-100 simultaneous users).

The configuration is done by my ISP, who i trust, but i still would like to know if the configuration makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the best setup however it works for us.

A few things I updated with our nginx setup are:

The **worker_connections**, I believe that a browser opens two connections per request so you don't technically have 1024 available connections per request you have 512 so maybe change it to 2048.

I also changed the **error log** file param to "info" only as you have think about write times to keep the I/O low, So I changed it from "warn" to "info".

If you want to keep the **access log** maybe slim down the log entires it adds.

It might be worth looking at your master nginx.conf aswell you might have configs being overwritten by this file and being set back to default.

Just two little things I did from a big list I went through, however this article is great - [link](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/)

Comment: Thanks OliverBS. I Was specially wondering about the php-fpm configuration, since php-fpm processes eat all the memory we've got. Is the max_children =  900 smart?

Comment: Hey, I am running ubuntu so might not be the same but I installed ab via apt and then installed htop so I could see the memory usage creep up and I then let ab send a load of requests and tracked the memory usage as I set the max_children and also the children waiting to pickup the processes, I would say get some benchmarking tools and test it until you get the perfect setup. Does this help ?